# Two flavors of red-black trees with different performance

Tags: trees, binary-trees, binary-search

I've implemented two red-black trees (using the pseudo-code in CLRS) with slightly different flavors:

1) In the first tree, all the data is stored in the leaves.

2) In the second tree, the data is stored in the internal nodes.

In an application I have, I have many insertions and deletions.  The performance of the first red-black tree is orders of magnitude faster than the second (about 200 times faster).

I expected the second tree to be faster because it has about half as many nodes.  So this performance difference surprised me.

While it is possible that I did not implement them comparably, are there any other reasons for this performance difference (perhaps pertaining to the many insertions and deletions in the application)?

Comment: It is somewhat hard to tell without seeing the code. You can try profiling your code to see where exactly the performance differs. You could have also made a mistake in the slower variant, which could cause it (for example) not to be balanced, or even some more trivial mistakes.

Comment: It's hard to imagine a 200-fold difference without there being an algorithmic bug.